# How can I link to jnigraphics in Android 2.1?

Tags: android, android-ndk

I have an app which uses jnigraphics but I need it to be available for Android 2.1 (since ~25%  users still have that.) I'm trying to bundle it but having difficulty with the linking.

My Android.mk is as follows:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE := jnigraphics-prebuilt
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := lib/libjnigraphics.so
LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/include

include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE    := yyy
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := yyy.c
LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARY := jnigraphics-prebuilt
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/include
LOCAL_LDLIBS    += -lm -llog
#LOCAL_CFLAGS    += -O3

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

It now recognises `#include <android/bitmap.h>` (I was getting an error about that before adding the C_INCLUDES lines) but still doesn't seem to be linking the library, because when building I get undefined references to symbols which are in the (apparently) successfully included header file:

```
Prebuilt       : libjnigraphics.so <= jni/lib/
Install        : libjnigraphics.so => libs/armeabi/libjnigraphics.so
Compile thumb  : yyy <= yyy.c
SharedLibrary  : libyyy.so
/home/xxx/w/zzz/obj/local/armeabi/objs/yyy/yyy.o: In function `Java_yyy_yyy_yyy_MainActivity_yyy':
/home/xxx/w/zzz/jni/yyy.c:143: undefined reference to `AndroidBitmap_getInfo'
```

**Update:**

The solution is to provide both the directory containing the library in LDLIBS -L and the name of the library in LDLIBS -l, e.g.:

`LOCAL_LDLIBS += -L$(PROJECT_PATH)/libs/$(TARGET_ARCH_ABI)/ -ljnigraphics -lm -llog`

You must also load the newly embedded library in the class where you use it, e.g.:

```
public native static byte[] doYYY(Bitmap bitmap); static {
    System.loadLibrary("jnigraphics");
    System.loadLibrary("yyy");
}
```

Many thanks to Richard Puckett for this solution.

**Update 2:**

It's possible that vendors (and firmware mods like CY) might interfere with this API, so it shouldn't be depended on.