# Unsatisfied Link Error - Could not find Library

Tags: android, c, android-ndk

I'm attempting to load the libjnigraphics.so prebuilt library to my project, however when I deploy the application, I am receiving this error:

```
06-17 22:35:28.741: INFO/dalvikvm(298): Unable to dlopen(/data/data/com.foo/lib/libndkfoo.so): Cannot load library: link_image[1721]:    29 could not load needed library 'libjnigraphics.so' for 'libndkfoo.so' (load_library[1051]: Library 'libjnigraphics.so' not found)
```

[image: error]

It compiles perfectly, fine.

Here's my Android.mk as well:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

# Add prebuilt libjnigraphics
include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE := libjnigraphics
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := libjnigraphics.so
LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/include

include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)


include $(CLEAR_VARS)

# Here we give our module name and source file(s)
LOCAL_MODULE    := ndkfoo
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := ndkfoo.c
LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARY := libjnigraphics
#LOCAL_LDLIBS += -libjnigraphics
LOCAL_LDLIBS += -llog

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

Is there a special place I need to put the libjnigraphics.so? Right now I have it in the jni folder, however I've tried it in multiple other places and it still fails. Any help?

Comment: Have you looked in the resulting APK to insure that the files are included there? You might also try putting them in an "armeabi" directory under "libs" (or "armeabi-v7a" for ARMv7 code) - this is where I always place native libraries, but I was never sure whether that was because of the build environment or the execution environment.

Comment: I've tried putting them in the armeabi, but no dice. I'll check the APK, but I'm betting it's probably not there.

Also, why are there downvotes and votes to close? What's wrong with the question?

Comment: You shouldn't put it into your project. The library will in the target devices. Just use -libjnigraphics.

Comment: The goal is to get this running on 2.1 devices without access to jnigraphics, such that I can load bitmaps through the LoadBitmap function, otherwise unaccessible.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4833572/android-ndk-and-rendering-to-live-wallpapers/5752325#5752325

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The device has to be [running Foyo](http://developer.android.com/sdk/ndk/overview.html#tools) (Android 2.2, target platform android-8) to be able to use libjnigraphics.so. It doesn't matter what is in your SDK or project directories, this library is part of the device's system libraries.

You can compile your code using the NDK with android-8, but then it will give link-time errors when you side-load the apk and your device happens to be running 2.1 or earlier.

There's this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6156131) with a workaround, but it shouldn't be relied upon and will crash on some devices. Here's a [post on the android-ndk group](http://groups.google.com/group/android-ndk/browse_thread/thread/bef82644938a2785) explaining the issues.

Comment: I realize this, and my goal is to add jnigraphics to my project as per this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4833572/android-ndk-and-rendering-to-live-wallpapers/5752325#5752325

I will look more into the workaround later, though I agree it shouldn't be relied upon. 

How would you suggest loading a bitmap into native code if I am unable to call bitmap.h files?

Comment: Depends what it's for: Take the hit on copying the bitmap's data array, use Open GL have the bitmap as a texture, rewrite the bitmap-altering code in Java, or abandon support for <= 2.1...

Comment: As David Turner, the tech lead on the android NDK, says on that android-ndk mailing list thread: "[high performance graphics are] simply not possible on Eclair. Your trick is probably the best way to do it, but isn't 100% safe."

Answer (score 0):

just try these changes:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
```

# Add prebuilt libjnigraphics

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE := graphics-prebuilt

LOCAL_SRC_FILES := libjnigraphics.so

LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/include

include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

```
# Here we give our module name and source file(s)
```

LOCAL_MODULE    := ndkfoo

LOCAL_SRC_FILES := ndkfoo.c

LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARY := graphics-prebuilt

LOCAL_LDLIBS += -llog

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)